# Speeding up kernel recompile

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compilation, linux-kernel

I am trying to hack kernel. But even if I modify one file, the incremental compilation takes about 10 minutes, with a lot of time spent checking that no driver modules have been updated (There seems to be a lot of device drivers). Since I am not modifying my device drivers, is there a way to ask the make subsystem in kernel to ignore any updates to device drivers folder or to specify to it that only files in certain directory have changed?

Comment: Do you call `GNU make` directly ? I've not built the kernel for a long time but I think you can use the `-jX` option with `X` your number of processor cores. You can also try `-r` to disable the built-in rules, but it's possible this doesn't work if the Makefile relies on built-in rules.

Comment: Take a look at ccache

Comment: Usually when your compiling the kernel incremental only parts of code gets compiled when you rebuild, yes if you are changing the header files, all the files which include those will again rebuild the drivers. You can speed up a little by -jN (where N is number of preprocessors)

Comment: Just run make -j4 and it will build in very short time.